# Kubernetes hybrid cluster (cloud/on premises) setup documentation?

Tags: kubernetes, hybrid

i just wondered if there's any documentation about how to setup a hybrid k8s cluster (which resides in parts on local on-premises components but can scale into the cloud, either with nodes or even a master). I'm aware of the federation feature, but this only covers two individual clusters, not a single one which scales dynamically into the cloud. Is there any documentation about such a scenario? At least some do's and dont's?

I've got some basic ideas on how build a cluster like this, but perhaps there's some info on how to avoid some common pitfalls.

I already searched quite a lot of documentation, but you only get results for the federation feature or 'hybrid' as in mixed linux/windows clusters...

Comment: Hi, As I Understand, I am applying the following topology to create a hybrid cloud at on-premises and on AKZ(Azure).[hub-spoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/hub-spoke)

Comment: I was just reading this very interesting story of multi-zone etcd under kubernetes, has some applicable guidance: https://monzo.com/blog/2017/11/29/very-robust-etcd/